# How could I easily expand a list of numbers with hyphens replacing repeated parts?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

**ATTENTION! I have changed the RegEx and sample data so some answers could be wrong! I apologize if doing this is bad practice.**

I used grep (online tool) to extract a list of data where repeated parts are sometimes substituted with hyphens (-o flag). The numbers are always 8 digits. There may be more 8-digit numbers following these
RegEx used was: `[0-9]{8}(, -[0-9]*)*(, [0-9]{8})*`
Sample data below:

```
33520470
33520850, -60, -70, -80, -90, 33630077
25453810
13815206, -07, -08, 60682651, 60709994
13340820
61040146, -55
60819060, -79
60819088
```

And my desired output would be:

```
33520470
33520850
33520860
33520870
33520880
33520890
33630077
25453810
13815206
13815207
13815208
60682651
60709994
13340820
61040146
61040155
60819060
60819079
60819088
```

Could this be done with grep? If not, could you suggest any unix or other tools to achieve this result? I was thinking sed or awk.

**EDIT: This has been solved. I will include the correct command here just for convenience to skip having to dig through the comments:**

`-F ', ' '{ print $1; for(a=2;a <= NF; a ++){ if(length($a) <= 7){ printf("%s%s\n",substr($1,1,length($1)-(length($a)-1)),substr($a, 2))} else { print $a } } }'`

Comment: You can't use grep for that. awk will work, but you will need a small program to do it.

Comment: Are the hyphened parts always exactly two digits?

Comment: There may be up to 7, the hyphen substitutes the repeating parts of the numbers. It would be safer to cover all possible occurrences.

Comment: I am not sure about the version, I am using the website https://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp

Comment: This can still be done with grep, but with the new conditions it is definitely better handled by awk and sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it with awk:

```
cat file | awk -F ', ' '{ print $1; for(a=2;a <= NF; a ++){printf("%s%s\n",substr($1,1,length($1)-(length($a)-1)),substr($a, 2)) } }'
```

Output:

```
33520470
33520850
33520860
33520870
33520880
33520890
25453810
13340820
61040146
61040155
60819060
60819079
60819088
```

---

Edit:

Code to get correct result:

```
cat file | awk -F ', ' '{ print $1; for(a=2;a <= NF; a ++){ if(length($a) <= 3){ printf("%s%s\n",substr($1,1,length($1)-(length($a)-1)),substr($a, 2))} else { print $a } } }'
```

Result:

```
33520470
33520850
33520860
33520870
33520880
33520890
33630077
25453810
13815206
13815207
13815208
60682651
60709994
13340820
61040146
61040155
60819060
60819079
60819088
```

Comment: This works well. Does awk support RegEx? Could it be tweaked further to include what grep does in the first example? Currently I have to use grep and then your solution on grep's output.

Comment: @SigmundFreud Yes, awk supports regex: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_regular_expressions.htm  but I think that using multiple commands to get result is not bad solution.

Comment: I discovered that I had an error in my RegEx. The new one is `[0-9]{8}(, -[0-9]*)*(, [0-9]{8})*` and returns rows with more 8-digit numbers such as `13815206, -07, -08, 60682651, 60709994` which does not work with that command. The solution worked perfectly with the previously provided data set, however!

Comment: @SigmundFreud The difference is in these numbers? `-07` `-08`

Comment: @SigmundFreud I edited code, try it now.

Comment: With the row `13815206, -07, -08, 60682651, 60709994` I get the output:
`13815206,13815207,13815208,10682651,10709994`
but the expected output would be:
`13815206, 13815207, 13815208, 60682651, 60709994`

Comment: @SigmundFreud That's correct, right? Or what is the expected output?

Comment: The first digits of the last two numbers get substituted (6 to 1)

Comment: @SigmundFreud Got it, I read modified question. Try it now (edited answer)

Comment: Sorry, I still get the exact same results (6 changed to 1 on the first digits)

Comment: @SigmundFreud Did you try edited code? I posted also output and it's same as yours.

Comment: Yes. Double checked. I am using https://awk.js.org/ and pasting `-F ', ' '{ print $1; for(a=2;a <= NF; a ++){ if(length($a <= 3)){ printf("%s%s\n",substr($1,1,length($1)-(length($a)-1)),substr($a, 2))} else { print $a } } }'`

Comment: @SigmundFreud show me your output, please.

Comment: 13815206
13815207
13815208
10682651
10709994

Comment: @SigmundFreud I am still not smart from it. Please, post result with my code and expected result.

Comment: Same as before, result with code `13815206 13815207 13815208 10682651 10709994` expected result `13815206 13815207 13815208 60682651 60709994` (do not overwrite the 6's)

Comment: @SigmundFreud I am sorry, my bad, I put  ')' on the wrong place. Try it now, it should be ok.

Comment: You did it! It works perfectly now.

Comment: It didn't work with substitutions longer than 2 but changing ```if(length($a <= 3)``` to ```if(length($a <= 7)``` seems to have fixed this

Comment: @SigmundFreud Yes, 3 in this if is for detecting whole number or number for substitution.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** with a pre-processing step to handle the modified input.

The rest of this answer assumes that the data has been pre-processed with

```
grep -oE '[0-9]{8}(, -[0-9]+)*'
```

I.e., the full solution would require

```
grep -oE ... file | awk ...
```

---

```
BEGIN { FS = ", *" }

{
    print $1
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
        print substr($1, 1, length($1) - length($i) + 1) substr($i, 2)
}
```

This `awk` script reads a line and then prints the first comma-delimited field.  It then loops over the remaining fields and outputs the first field with enough characters cut off at the end to insert the characters after the `-` in the other fields.

The code allows for "suffixes" of variable length.

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
33520470
33520850
33520860
33520870
33520880
33520890
25453810
13340820
61040146
61040155
60819060
60819079
60819088
```

Another example:

```
$ cat file
1111
2222,-3,-4, -33,-44, -333,-444
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
1111
2222
2223
2224
2233
2244
2333
2444
```

---

As a "one-liner":

```
awk -F ', *' '{print $1; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i)print substr($1,1,length($1)-length($i)+1)substr($i,2)}' file
```